# Is there a way to disable Redshift password requirements?

Tags: amazon-redshift

According to Amazon Redshift docs, the passwords must be at least 8 chars, and contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, and one number.

Is there a way to disable this for a database?

We do not need such stringent requirements.

Also, the docs are unclear, but if I don't specify VALID UNTIL 'something' then it is valid forever, right? (The docs say you can also use VALID UNTIL 'infinity' but don't explain what would happen if you don't include VALID UNTIL at all)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the Redshift password criteria.

If you are referring to `ALTER USER ... [VALID UNTIL]`, the validity date is not a required field. The password will remain valid forever.

Answer (score 0):

By using the md5 function, you can get around the lengh/char requirements:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_USER.html

In particular, quoting from the above page:

To specify an MD5 password, follow these steps:

Concatenate the password and user name.

For example, for password ez and user user1, the concatenated string is ezuser1.

Convert the concatenated string into a 32-character MD5 hash string. You can use any MD5 utility to create the hash string. The following example uses the Amazon Redshift MD5 Function and the concatenation operator ( || ) to return a 32-character MD5-hash string.

select md5('ez' || 'user1');

### md5

153c434b4b77c89e6b94f12c5393af5b

Concatenate 'md5' in front of the MD5 hash string and provide the concatenated string as the md5hash argument.

create user user1 password 'md5153c434b4b77c89e6b94f12c5393af5b';
Log on to the database using the user name and password.

For this example, log on as user1 with password ez.